# Accessing to Gedmo soft deleted entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, gedmo-tree

In annotations for the class of User entity, I have:

```
@Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", hardDelete=false)
```

And later in code:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $deletedAt;
```

Soft delete works fine, but I want modification so soft deleted User still can be accessed, for example with `$message->getSentBy()`. Because User foreign key is in another table.

In class Message I have the field:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="locked_by", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $sentBy;
```

And now because of soft delete, wherever regular active Users want to see messages sent by soft deleted User **I get an error invalid user (the User entity is not found).**

Is there any way to modify soft delete so it is selectable on places where another foreign key uses that field? Or to be available to use on select statements.

I am using Symfony 5.4 on PHP 7.4

Comment: You should implement an EventSuscriber that look on KernelEvent request, if match with specific action, or users roles for example: then disable softdeleteable filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disable the filter when you need to access "deleted" entities:

```
$em->getFilters()->disable('soft-deleteable');
$art = $repo->findOneBy(array('title' => 'My Article'));

// or
// Enable / Disable filter filter, for specified entity (default is enabled for all)
$filter = $em->getFilters()->enable('soft-deleteable');
$filter->disableForEntity('Entity\Article');
$filter->enableForEntity('Entity\Article');
```

see https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/blob/main/doc/softdeleteable.md#usage